# Can I write katakana words in alternative ways?

Tags: katakana, loanwords

When I write words that are purely in katakana, I always forgot whether to add a ッ or a ー. For example, When writing スクリーンショット, I might write スクリンショト or スクリーンショト or even スクリンショト. My question is, does these things matter? Do people understand what a スクリンショト is?

I am aware that it might become another entirely different word, like ビール vs ビル but surely that can be inferred from context, right?

Comment: Are you inputting the text using an input method editor? You can select the correct spelling from the list of suggestions.

Comment: What if I'm writing on paper? @siikamiika

Comment: As in English, writing a word incorrectly might be understood, but it is still not correct.

Comment: @JACKB But as in English, words can be spelled in more than one "correct" way, like learned vs learnt and sulfur vs sulphur.

Comment: ＠Sweeper Recognized spellings are the determining factor in both languages.

Comment: It's akin to using the wrong their, there, they're in English; people can generally figure out what you mean, but it's really not a good look. It's fine to make mistakes as you learn, but I'd advise against willful ignorance as to correct spellings because 1) they add up over time 2) you don't want to encode them into your memory incorrectly 3) you may find yourself in a situation where someone judges you on your (in)ability to write and that'd be an inopportune occasion to misspell something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrongly written words in katakana look quite strange, weird and odd.
Though one may be able to understand these words after staring at them for a second, they are not at all alternative ways of writing, but just wrong ones.

The reason is that their pronunciations are definitely different.
If you omit 「ッ」 or 「ー」 in words, the pronunciations change even though 「ッ」 and 「ー」 may look supplementary. So they are unlikely to be regarded identical.

The exception is trailing 「ー」. For example 「サーバー」 and 「サーバ」 for "server."
In this case both are accepted (so some standards define which ones to use).